# Java JIT and boxing

Tags: java, optimization, jit

I came across code written by a colleague:

```
return new Integer(_hash).compareTo(other.getHash());
```

and I am wondering if Java can optimize this avoid the boxing and simply compare the two integers. Does it do that (in Java 7 or 8), or does it continue creating an Integer and calling compareTo() each time?

Comment: In general the JITC would not attempt to completely "optimize away" the creation of an object.

Comment: Interesting... thanks!

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not sure about the state of the art, but there are tons of papers already for JDK7 e.g., [this](http://blog.juma.me.uk/2008/12/17/objects-with-no-allocation-overhead) (I haven't read it yet).

Comment: In general, a JITC must assure that any side-effect that would have occurred under the interpreter will occur in JITCed code as well.  Thus, while an object allocation may be changed to stack allocation, and a constructor may be inlined, the actual object construction will almost certainly occur.  In the above case the JITC would have to recognize this very special case, since two object creations would have to be blocked in order to realize the benefits.  Generally a JITC writer is wrestling alligators and has bigger fish to fry (to mix metaphors).

Comment: @HotLicks not sure I agree on this. After escape analysis the constructor here is basically a write to stack memory.. clearly the register allocator should take care of that. Will have to check assembly sometime, but it seems reasonably doable.

Comment: A stack-allocated object is still technically "constructed".  What's saved is the allocation and garbage collection that a heap-allocated object would require.  A JITC may be able to determine that some of the construction process (eg, setting the class pointer) can be eliminated, but with the (presumably inlined) method call there it gets messy fast.  And, of course, if the method is not inlined then there is really nothing that can be eliminated.  Not saying it couldn't be done, but I greatly doubt that it *would* be done, since it doesn't appear to be a "hot" scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 7 and 8, surely you should just use [`Integer.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29). Then you can totally avoid any boxing whatsoever. Simple!